# STMCubeIDE on NUCLEO STM32F334R8, new project: FreeRTOS hardfault

Tags: stm32, freertos, stm32cubeide

I want to experiment with 32 bit microcontrollers and FreeRTOS. I'm creating a new project in STM32CubeIDE for my Nucleo board and I enable FreeRTOS. I Switch the Timer used by the HAL (i'm basically following this video but with another nucleo board https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPrcpbKNSjU). When I start debug mode, it immediately calls the Hardfaulthandler when starting the task scheduler by executing osKernelStart(); I have no idea why. The only thing that my tasks are doing now is toggling the LED pin A5...

Comment: No code no answer. Probably wrong interrupt priorities.

Comment: there's no code, except for the default generated freertos code...

Comment: if there is no code - there is no freeRTOS too. And no LED flashing

Comment: EXCEPT FOR THE DEFAULT GENERATED CODE BY THE IDE.

Comment: really. So you not compile anything as there is no code. Is it the truth? If yes it is magic. No code but blinking.

Comment: there's no code that I wrote, but there's code generated by the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was/is an issue with cubeide 1.4.0 generating broken code (NVIC setup, INT prios) code causing a hardfault when using FreeRTOS.
The issue was reported to ST.

Comment: Is there a workaround? Downgrade tot previous version of the Ide?

Comment: Downgrade is an option and I know that 1.3.1 works. I don’t know if it’s meanwhile fixed by a new release.

Comment: thank you very much! First steps now with 32 bit microcontrollers are working!